# PHP: when i display my table and i hit an empty value i want it to throw an error

Tags: php, arrays, loops

i'm looking for a answer to one problem i currently have.
I have a table that displays 48 rows and something like 10 collumns.
Most of the collumns are filled in with values but some are empty.
I want to find those fields en give it a red border so that they pop out when i display it in a table.

Currently i'm joining 2 tables together and display them with a while loop.
Is there a way to select the empty cell and make the border red?

table:
------------------------------
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
|------|---------|------|------|
| test | empty | test | test |
|------|---------|------|------|

so i want that empty cell to have a red border.

What i have at the moment table:
------------------------------
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
|------|---------|------|------|
| empty |
|------|---------|------|------|
If more info is needed i would be happy to provide.

Comment: yes, each row could be tested for NULL or empty string in order to change the behaviour

Comment: you can use jQuery to make a click on a cell and then check it if its empty otherwise send an ajax request, or with the page reload add a link to every cell to make a request every time you click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using table, you can try something like this inside your loop that is displaying the data

```
<?php
if ($yourvariable == NULL || $yourvariable == "" ){
    ?>
    <td class="your colored class"></td>
<?php
}
    else{
    ?>
    <td class="your non colored class"></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You've got a typo, `!!` it should be `||`

Comment: i form my table in the while loop.
so my echo is: <tr><td>" . $GSM_Id . "</td><td>" . $GSM_Spec . "</td></tr>
Can i still use that then?

Comment: @Maikel yes you can, you should put the `if` after `<tr>`

Comment: inside the echo? So then to avoid errors it would be:
echo "<tr>"
 ?>
 <?php
  if ($row == NULL || $row == "" ){
   ?>
 <td style='border: solid 3px red;'></td>
 <?php
  }
  else{
   ?>
<td></td>
<?php
}
"<td>" . $GSM_Id . "</td></tr>";